# Best way to get a substring when knowing the last index and how many characters to take before that in C#

Tags: c#, linq, substring

Say I have a string `abcdefghi`

I would like to extract from that the string `cdef`

I know that the index of the last character I want is 5 (which is f).

I also know that I want to take the 3 preceding characters with it.

Here is my code so far, which does work, but doesn't look that pretty. Is there a better way?

```
string text = "abcdefghi";
int lastIndex = 5;
int numberOfCharsToTake = 4  // including the last index char

Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join("",
    text
    .Substring(0, lastIndex + 1)
    .Reverse()
    .Take(numberOfCharsToTake)
    .Reverse()
    )
)
```

Comment: _"Best way..."_ might be _subject to opinion_ and if so is sadly off-topic for SO. [ask].  Consider re-phrasing your question to be [constructive subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper Your right, Will change now

Comment: and it's till opinion-based because of the "better way". What is *better*? Less lines of code? Faster? Less memory-consuming?...

Comment: Why you did not use a simple `Substring` which is for sure the most efficient and also straight forward way?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I was asking for a more pretty way / elegant syntax. Not "what is  better"

Comment: @YossiSternlicht okay, but those are still opinion based. People have different perceptions of what is pretty and what is elegant. You don't have a clear problem here, so this isn't suitable for Stack Overflow. May be  suitable for Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string text = "abcdefghi";
string lastIndex = 5;
string numberOfCharsToTake = 4  // including the last index char

Console.WriteLine(
    text.Substring(lastIndex - numberOfCharsToTake, numberOfCharsToTake)
);
```

Comment: Because the OP's question wasn't _constructive subjective_ whereby _["...insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references..."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_ inevitably leads to people posting answers with unjustified conclusions or unproven claims such as yours (in fact you don't have any to say why it's the _"best way"_).   You can easily benchmark it

Comment: But definitely this answer presents a "better way" than the original code in all meanings of "better" I can imagine.

Comment: I came to improve the code in the question, this is not a reason to deduct points for it @MickyD

Comment: People's votes are theirs to use as they see fit soong as they aren't serially targeting a specific user. Please do not tell others how to use their votes.

Comment: It's completely clear to me :)
But I just helped the questioner, anyway good luck to everyone :)

Comment: The result of this answer is not what OP expected, it must be `lastIndex - numberOfCharsToTake + 1` because OP wants to include the char at lastIndex.

Comment: _"best way"_ aside, consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Comment: @MickyD: I don't agree with that(at least the deletion part). While it is always better to provide at least a link to the documentation or an explaining sentence, code only can be enough to answer a very specific question(which is the best question).

Comment: @HaimAbeles _"I came to improve the code in the question, this is not a reason to deduct points for it MickyD "_ - Here I am giving you friendly advice on how to `improve your answer` and you go and accuse me of down-voting?  Please don't take things personally.

Comment: @TimSchmelter this is exactly why these sort of questions shouldn't be answered.